# application launch animation works only when running from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a view like what i have in `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and I'm scaling that at run with this code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        self.aftab_logo.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
        self.aftab_logo.alpha = 0
        self.login_content.alpha=1
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.aftab_logo.removeFromSuperview()
    })
```

When I'm closing app and running again from device this animation doesn't show but when I'm running app from Xcode everything is fine. what is the problem?

Comment: have you tried after terminating or closing your app? because if your app is in background then it will start with viewcontroller last you have leave!

Comment: yes I'm closing it from recent applications and launchscreen shows but scale animation don't works @Lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `viewDidload` get called before you `UI` gets layout. so, if you want any animation related you `scaling` any object then you should use `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidload`.

Now if you want animation only one time when user start app not when user come to first screen with navigating back then you should set some `flag` and can store it's value somewhere to manage it.

So, take a try in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidload`!

**Update :**

I have made one demo something like your setup and it works fine in `viewDidload` also. main issue is your duration is very small for `viewdidload` to run it.

Once try to change your duration like **`2.0`** and you will found your animation working perfact!

Comment: Check my updated answer! increase your duration because you are not giving sufficient time to show it!

Comment: yeah i found thats the problem not the viewdidload or viewdidapper. but wt*? why second run duration is about half of first duration?

Comment: When you run project from your xcode to your device, it will take some extra time so you able to show your animation but if your app is already in your device memory then it runs more quickly, there are many reasons related to memory management, caching etc but they are beyond the scope of this question. you should increase your duration that perfectly suit with your requirement. that is the solution for your current issue!! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It may be just the cache of your device that's loading a previous implementation, try to delete the application from your device and run again.